# dataframe: how to get columns of Period objects (calendar+fiscal year and month)from DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, period, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe and these are the first 5 index, there are several rows with different datapoint for a date and then it goes to the next day

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-01',
               '2014-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='DayStartedOn', freq=None)
```

and this is the current column dtypes

```
country                  object
type                     object
name                     object
injection               float64
withdrawal              float64
cy_month              period[M]
```

I wish to add a column with calendar year month, and 2 columns with different fiscal years and months.
better to separate year and month in different columns like: calendar year, calendar month, fiscal year, fiscal month. The objective is to keep these column values when I perform regroup or resample with other columns

I achieved above cy_month by

```
df['cy_month']=df.index.to_period('M')
```

even I don't feel very comfortable with this, as I want the period, not the monthend

I tried to add these 2 columns
for calendar year:

```
pd.Period(df_storage_clean.index.year, freq='A-DEC')
```

for another fiscal year:

```
pd.Period(df_storage_clean.index.year, freq='A-SEP')
```

but had Traceback:

```
ValueError: Value must be Period, string, integer, or datetime
```

So I started to NOT using pandas by loop row by row and add to a list,

```
lst_period_cy=[]
for y in lst_cy:
    period_cy=pd.Period(y, freq='A-DEC')
    lst_period_cy.append(period_cy)
```

then convert the list to a Series or df and add it back to the df

but I suppose it's not efficient (150k rows data) so haven't continued

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you haven't found a solution yet ...

You could do the following:

```
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df['cal_year_month'] = df.DayStartedOn.dt.month
df['cal_year'] = df.DayStartedOn.dt.year
df['fisc_year'] = df.DayStartedOn.apply(pd.Period, freq='A-SEP')
df.set_index('DayStartedOn', drop=True, inplace=True)
```

My assumption is that, as in your example, the index is named `DayStartedOn`. If that's not the case then the code has to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, df['fisc_year'] = df.DayStartedOn.apply(pd.Period, freq='A-SEP') is definitely an interesting way.